# php quotes sent along with variable help

Tags: php, html, database, variables, solr

I am sending this to a function, and I want double-quotes around the value of the variable below, example `$var = "New York"` (note the quotes)

```
   $fq.=" + area:$state";
```

So when I echo $state I want double quotes around it, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is a basic RFTM question, if you have to ask questions like these, you aren't ready for StackOverflow (or any help forum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
$fq .= " + area:\"$state\"";
```

The backslash escapes special characters(like newline, tabs or quotes) in double quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = '"New York"';
```